# iOS third party providers authorization to Supabase

Tags: swift, authorization, google-signin, supabase, apple-sign-in

In my iOS app I'm using the following providers for authorization: **Apple**, **Google** and **Facebook**. The authorization flow is done via the frameworks: **`AuthenticationServices`** for Apple Sign In, **`GoogleSignIn`** for Google and **`FBSDKLoginKit`** for Facebook.

When authorization is completed successfully I receive a credential for each provider, that contains the following data:

1. For Apple I got an `idToken` and `nonce`.
2. For Google I got an `idToken` and `accessToken`.
3. For Facebook I got an `accessToken`.

The question is: How do I continue the authorization flow to Supabase? How to send this credentials in order to receive a valid authorization session?

UPDATE:

I managed to accomplish the Apple Sign In by posting `idToken` and `nonce` to `https://SUPABASE_ID.supabase.co/auth/v1/token?grant_type=id_token`.
But it is still not clear how to proceed with **Google** and **Facebook** providers.

Comment: Hi! I've got exactly the same issue: how to login using the Google idToken. Did you manage to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @cjgaliana Hi. Not yet unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @ios-dev. It's such a pity that is not possible. This way is totally missing the "native" way yo login into google when using a mobile app :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented anywhere, and I got to this just reading the goTrue source code. So not sure if that will stop working anytime soon. But in case it's useful for anyone else...

Just make a POST request to

```
https://<your id>.supabase.co/auth/v1/token?grant_type=id_token
```

With the body

```
{"id_token": "<your google id_token>","provider": "google"}
```

Add a apikey header with your Supabase Key and you will get the auth response from supabase. Then call "`setSession()`" with that access token and refresh token and your are good to go.